# Reference subfigure by letter only

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I have a figure with multiple subfigures. When I reference a subfigure using, for example, `Figure \ref{subfig:a}`, it (correctly) renders as **Figure 1.1a**.

However, if I chain many such references together, it would render as, for example, **Figure 1.1a-1.1b, as well as 1.1d and 1.1f**. I think it would read easier if I could get it to render as **Figure 1.1a-b, as well d and f**.

I would like a way to suppress the figure number and only display the alphabetical subfigure identifier when referencing a subfigure. Also, I would like to do this on command, only for some references, rather than changing the default behaviour for my document.

For context, I use the `caption` and `subcaption` packages to manage subfigures.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `\subref`-command (from section 6.1 in the [subcaption docs](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
Figure letter: \subref{fig:1a}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:
[image]